# Doesn't Expression Tree support dynamic generic type parameters?

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic, expression-trees

I'd like to dynamically create generic classes. To define type parameters you will call `DefineGenericParameters` method on `TypeBuilder`s and you can add type constraints on the type parameters with the return value.

By the way, I'm using Expression Tree to emit the method body. But then I realized that the APIs of Expression Tree don't accept `GenericTypeParameterBuilder`s, which is the return value of the `DefineGenericParameters` method, as arguments.
Maybe you are wondering whether it will compile. Because the type is derived from `Type` so it will compile. But the APIs of Expression Tree throw exceptions at runtime, telling me that the type contains a generic type parameter on Mono and that the method is not supported on .NET.

So it seems to me that Expression Tree can't handle generic type parameters, but is it really so? Am I missing something?
If so, I will be happy if you are suggesting other ways to handle generic type parameters using Expression Tree.

Comment: `Expression` tree are severly limited in what you can do with reflection-emitted new classes. I don't even know if you can create "plain" instance methods.

Comment: Ah... I would say the answer is yes and no. You can emit static methods using `LambdaExpression.CompileToMethod`. But since it emits only static methods, you need a trick if you are emitting instance methods.

Comment: I wrote instance but I should have written **instance** :-) Yes... As you can see Expression trees at this time aren't a good instrument for complementing `TypeBuilder`.

Comment: That's really really true... sigh for those who want to go deeply into the CLR... :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the method is not supported on .NET.

This I can explain:

To check if the type is an enum, in the end [this](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/emit/typebuilderinstantiation.cs,229)  line is called:

```
public override bool IsSubclassOf(Type c)
{
    throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

by [this](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/type.cs,1097) line:

```
 public virtual bool IsEnum {
     get
     {
        return IsSubclassOf(RuntimeType.EnumType);
     }
```

that is called by [this](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/Microsoft/Scripting/Ast/ParameterExpression.cs,43) line:

```
internal static ParameterExpression Make(Type type, string name, bool isByRef) {
    if (isByRef) {
        return new ByRefParameterExpression(type, name);
    } else {
        if (!type.IsEnum) {
```

Now... About your question: no can do. Sadly the two subsystems (`Reflection.Emit` and `Expression`) aren't much "compatible". As you know creating instance methods (including constructors) with `LambaExpression.CompileToMethod()` isn't supported. The only thing you can do is create plain (non-generic) static methods that don't include the type being constructed with `TypeBuilder` in its parameters.

Comment: Actually, that answer is what I expected. I was just not sure if I was right. Thank you very much.